# AdSense not allowed on adult page or site?

Tags: google-adsense

On the same page [Google guideline](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en) is telling me two contradictory things under the same paragraph.

> (a) Publishers may not place AdSense code **on pages with content** [...]
>
> (b) **Sites with Google ads** may not include or link to: Pornography, adult or mature content [...]

I have a "large" webpage (+500'000 pages). 80% is safe content. 20% is adult content.

I only use AdSense on the safe pages.

Is it compliant?

PS: Of course, I do not dare to ask Google. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I specifically asked Google about this.  You can have adult content on your site, but it has to be in its own section and can't have ads.  The section of your sites with ads can't link to the adult section at all.   Two clicks is fine.   My ad rep suggested an interstitial page saying "you are entering the adult section, continue?"  if you did want to link between the two sections, so that it would be more than one click.

Comment: I have had the same feedback. At least (as I know of), 3 Google reps reviewed my website, and I have never had any issue. I even sit with one of them and she checked the website with me. But it was a few years ago and terms evolve. Not sure it was still the case. When was your feedback given?

Comment: Very recent -- I asked two weeks ago.

Comment: @toto so did u follow this answer then? have u ran google ads on family safe pages but also had adult content on your site more than 2 clicks away with interstial? and ofcourse no google ads on this page but on the rest of family safe site . let me know your experience, did u face any issues from google after doing this? coz i see it on reddit too.

Comment: @Faizan we ended up not allowing users to post adult content because it would have been too difficult to comply with this policy for us.

Comment: @Faizan Still no issue as long as you have distinct sections. Please note that an internal  link to the adult section is also considered as adult content.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar questions before and from personal experience Google doesn't want its advertisers being associated with any adult content full stop. Even if the ads are displayed on safe pages, the fact they are a click or two away is adult content. Google will not allow this and most likely terminate your whole ad sense account if discovered.

Terminations are life time and I recommend you don't even risk it.

Thanks
William

Comment: Do you have references (urls)? I felt that Google is voluntary blur on that. They can then "juge" the main intend of the website. Take cnn, they have pages with violence, death, guns, porn stories, etc. but are adsensable.